# Using OSGI bundles with sbt or maven

Tags: maven, osgi, sbt

I had this crazy idea since a long time so decided to finally ask. Is there some project for integrating bundles directly into the the build process without explicitly doing extra work of including an osgi container and adding bundles etc. So the basic idea being in you build.sbt or pom.xml you just specify your dependency like you normally do and instead of fetching the jars, sbt or mvn fetches bundles (if available) for your dependency. And on building the project a container of your choice would be downloaded and bundles (and jars) would be added to it automatically ? Just like a fairy tale.

EDIT: By the last part i meant something along the lines of felix gogo which will create a script for adding bundles to run container with them. Althogh thats too much to ask for but after the build i can just run a script and my whole project will run on an osgi container free from jar hell.

Answer (score 1):

This already works today. You simply use the [maven bundle plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) to create a bundle of your code during the build process. Many of the jars in maven central already are bundles. So you just specify them as normal dependencies.

I am not sure what you want to achieve in the last part. Downlaoding the container and adding the bundles. The build process just creates the jar. Why should it load a container?

If you want to do this for testing purposes then [pax exam](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXEXAM3/Pax+Exam) is what you search. It does exactly what your describe for your unit tests. It downloads a container, adds your bundles and deploys and runs your test in the container.

Comment: I am sorry if i am not correct maven bundle plugin only makes bundle of your project. bundleall is already deprecated. What about other dependencies which are not bundles?, Is one supposed to manually make bundles out of them?

Comment: Today most of your dependencies in fact can be found as bundles. For example the servicemix project creates bundles of most libs I need (see http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22org.apache.servicemix.bundles%22). For the case where you want to inline classes the bundle plugin allows to define the foreign classes as private package. In this case it automatically adds these to your jar. In Apache Karaf you can also deploy plain jars as bundles using the wrap protocol. See http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.2/deploy_osgi/DeployJar-Wrap.html

Comment: That is really nice..but i dont see latest versions for most. Although i agree there is a awareness and people are deploying as bundles but not everyone..do you think it is possible to wrap the whole maven dependency as a bundle just oob? Does that makes sense?

Comment: I did not understand the last question. Do you mean to pack all dependencies into one bundle? In general I recommend to keep everything separate as you can have strange classloading problems if you pack many jars into one bundle.

Comment: Ok Just for example sake conside my project have dependency "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase" % "0.90.6-cdh3u5", now lets say i cant find a bundle for this anywhere. So if i create a bundle for my project all the jars which this dependency pulls will be added to my bundles manifest file as classpath which bring me back to square one. So instead i wanted to ask if there is an easy way to create a bundle for this dependency on which my projects bundle depend.

Comment: Yes. This is possible. You can look at the sources of the servicemix bundles to get an idea how to do it. In case of Habse this is not neccessary as it is available in the servicemix bundles. Ioannis Cannelos also wrote a blog entry about it: http://iocanel.blogspot.de/2012/07/apache-karaf-meets-apache-hbase.html